# Can I pass data from android fragment to java class after button click?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

In my parser class I declare an URL, but I want a search box where you can change an attribute in the URL after clicking on the button search.

Any idea how I can pass data from fragment to Java class?

Comment: You pass data to a class by calling a method on an instance of that class (or the class itself if it's a static method).

Answer (score 0):

```
final EditText searchTo = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.medittext);
searchTo.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        // TODO Provide Search with this URL
    } 
});
```